# Javascript Signalr client does not wait for server response

Tags: javascript, signalr

My Hub is :  (simplified)

```
public string BPF(string m1, string m2)
    {
        r = BiPoint4Clases.BiPoint4.getString(BP4Engine.Startup.cnxString, m2);// this gets a String from SQL Server accordig query passed on m2 hub parameter.
        return r;
}  
catch(Exeption e)
     {
      // manage exeptions. ....
     }
```

My Javascript client :

```
function GetString(z){
    bip.server.BPF("gS",z).done(function(result){array.push(result)});
}

//calling function to get string

GetString("select top 1 u from users");
alert(array);

//This returns nothing....
//function GetString, returns after .done() pushes result on array
```

How can I wait for server response for JavaScript function invoking hub returns.

Tried with `$.Deferred , $.when().then` but no results.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `GetString()` function your javascript is operating like this:

```
bip.server.BPF("gS",z).done(function(result){array.push(result)});
alert(array);
```

The `.done()` function is executed asynchronously. Meaning the script will jump right to the next statement, which is the `alert()`.

Basically you want to return the deferred object, and use that to handle the callback:

```
function GetString(z){
    return bip.server.BPF("gS",z);
}

GetString("select top 1 u from users").done(function(r) {
   array.push(r);
   alert(array);
});
```

Comment: i've tested but doesn't work.

SIGNALR hub returns result on deferred done(result)
bip.server.BPF("gS","select bla blabla....").done(function(r){    !here are result...    } );

If i call bip.server.BPF("gS","select bla blabla....") without  .done(   )
can never search for result.

(Sorry for my poor english)

Comment: continue:

in   GetString("select top 1 u from users").done(function(r) {
   array.push(r);      });     // !!!!!!!!r  IS AN DEFERRED OBJECT, not a string as expected!!!!